# Grunt-contrib-copy: variables within the rename function

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I have the following copy task in a `gruntfile.js`

```
copy: {
        css: {
            expand: true,      
            cwd: 'min/css',  
            src: 'theme_<%= props.majorversion %>.<%= props.minorversion %>.min.css',          
            dest: 'dest/dir/',
            rename: function(dest, src) {
                return dest + src.replace('_<%= props.majorversion %>.<%= props.minorversion %>','');
            }
        }
    }
```

Currently, the file is copied successfully but once copied, I'd like to remove the version numbers that make up part of the file name.

They are defined earlier in the gruntfile and are working as expected up until the rename function.

Current I get `file_1.123.css` and I'd like to end up with `file.css`.

I've tried various different ways to pass variables to the rename function but without success.

Thanks.

Comment: It's because by then the file is named and there for `_<%= props.majorversion %>.<%= props.minorversion %>` has been replaced already. Why call it one name and rename it after instead of just naming it what you want? Not familiar with rename method just wild guess

Comment: The initial file is already in existence and has a file name that might change. The new copy of the file is being used with Service Worker and is referenced in the file cache where it would be beneficial to have it with a static name that won't change.

Comment: Fair enough :) Is the file name converted if you console.log it inside rename function? If so a replace with regex may do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `substring` instead:

```
rename: function(dest, src) {
           return dest + src.substring(0, src.indexOf('_')) + '.css';
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's given me the result I was after.